# How to compare values of array and if they are equal make them one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hi I want to compare values in arrays and if they are same I want them to be considered as one.

```
var arrA = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
```

---

```
var arrB = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1 ,0.2,0.2,0.2 ,0.3,0.3 ,0.4,0.4]
```

What I want to do is to compare values of arrA if `arrA[i] == arrA[i+1]` then it should consider it as one value and in arrB the values of `arrB[i]` adds up with `arrB[i+1]`.

My final array shall look like this:

```
var arrA = [1,2,3,4]
```

---

var arrB = [0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8]

Can anyone help me with the javascript code for this. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the transformation: `[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1 ,0.2,0.2,0.2 ,0.3,0.3 ,0.4,0.4]` -> `[0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8]` seems to be summing the identical values, however  `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]` ->  `[1,2,3,4]` merely removes duplicates and leaves unique values.

Comment: @VLAZ it is sum

Comment: @Ghulam Ahmed, what have your tried so far?

Comment: But how do you choose which transformation to apply?

Comment: @VLAZ value in arrA is the label that has it's value in arrB at the same i'th position for instance the first value 0.1 is the label which has the value of 0.1 in arrB at the same i'th position. what is required that despite have same labels I want to combine them all that makes them one instead of duplicated and their values are added in arrB so for 4(1's) in arrA they are displayed as single 1 and their values 0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1 are added in arrB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array and check if the previous value is equal to the actual value.

```js
function sumSame(arrayA, arrayB) {
    var i,
        l = arrayA.length,
        resultA = [],
        resultB = [];

    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (arrayA[i] === arrayA[i - 1]) {
            resultB[resultB.length - 1] += arrayB[i];
        } else {
            resultA.push(arrayA[i]);
            resultB.push(arrayB[i]);
        }
    }
    return [resultA, resultB];
}

console.log(sumSame(
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4]
));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: great man I was expecting this but one thing that you have added the values or arrA that results as 4,6,6,8 I don't want to add them rather displayed as 1,2,3,4 while the corresponding arrB values are added as you've done that.

Comment: why no sum for the first array?

Comment: I am providing this array to a graph that is to be plotted against these values so 1,2,3,4 are the labels that are on x axis while values in arrB are the values against those labels. I don't want the labels to be added up, since the labels are being duplicated I want them to be considered once.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function with `reduce` method that takes an array and one more parameter that you can set to true or false and based on it you can just filter duplicates or also sum.

```js
const transform = (data, sum = false) => data.reduce((r, e, i) => {
  if (e != data[i - 1]) r.push(e)
  else {
    if (sum) r[r.length - 1] += e
  }
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(transform([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]));
console.log(transform([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4], true));
```

Answer (score 0):

For `arrA`You can use `Set` like below

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4.....];
const uniqueArr= Array.from(new Set(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

if not to use any other objects except array then for the first part of your question

```
const arrA = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4]
const arrAUnique = arrA
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .filter((v, ind, arr) => v !== arr[ind - 1])
```

For your second question solution with only array use

```
var arrB = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1 ,0.2,0.2,0.2 ,0.3,0.3 ,0.4,0.4]
var arrBSum = arrB
   .sort((a, b) => a - b)
   .reduce((newArr, v, ind, arr) => {
      if (v !== arr[ind - 1]) {
         newArr.push(v)
      }  else {
         newArr[newArr.length - 1] += v
      }
      return newArr
   }, [])
```

Comment: Nina has provided a solution if you can check that above, it's all okay expect addition of values of arrA which is not required.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a clean solution

```
// Find unique
const unique = arrA.reduce((result, curr) => {
 if(result.indexOf(curr)===-1) result.push(curr);
    return result
},[])
console.log(unique)//[1, 2, 3, 4]

//Find sum using reduce
var sum = (a, b) => a+b
var data = arrB.reduce((result, curr) => {
if(!result[curr]) result[curr] = []

result[curr].push(curr);
 return result
},{})
var arrSum = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key].reduce(sum).toFixed(1))
 console.log(arrSum) //[0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8]
```